# Spyder has encountered an internal problem. What steps will reproduce the problem?

Tags: python, mysql, pip, connectivity, mysql-connector-python

My code has no errors, I tried this same code on a different computer (it worked there) but here in my pc it isn't running. the following is a part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector 
conn= mysql.connector. connect(host="localhost", password='K#1703@sparks',user="root", database = "Buttercup_brew_cafe")
cur=conn. cursor()
sql = ("SELECT if null (max(Q Code)+1,1) FROM Bill;")
cur. execute( sql )
results = cur.fetchall()
for row in results:
    QCode=row[0]
```

the error.

[image]

I've also downloaded all the necessary packages for mysql connectivity with python such as `mysql-connector-python`, `mysql-connector`, `pandas`, `numpy` etc (using pip).
Can anyone help?

Comment: That's something you will need to take up with them, it's not a general programming question that we can answer

Comment: Hey! If your code worked on another machine it is likely that installed software differs. It is then helpful to provide the versions of the software that you used. If you click on `full details` you may find more information about why Spyder crashed.

Also: Please use code fences to format your code for better readability.

Comment: Oh Okay.. I got that. Well thanks for the help! @JHK

Comment: okay thank you @roganjosh